# Math "./" AND rem operation

Tags: vb.net, matlab, math, operators

I am studying Visual Basic .NET and I would like to convert one function in Matlab file.

However, I am not really sure how to convert the `./` operator to VB .Net

For `rem` function, I am sure that it must return remainder of division. Therefore, I convert `rem(low, high) = 0` to `low mod high = 0`.

However, I am not really sure how to convert `./` operation to VB .Net. For example, I have `low-high ./2` ... but I don't know what to use in VB .NET.

Does anyone know `./` operator in VB.NET?

#### Update

```
    function r = QPR(Low , high, step)
    if(Low < 0)
      return;
    end;
    if(low - high < 0)
      return;
    end;
    x = (Low-step ./2) + ((high + step ./2)* rand);
```

As I understand is correct from Tim example on the bottom. `./` is math operation of Array, so Low, high, step must be some kind of array.
However, it is subtracting each other such as (Low - step). 
I am getting confused that how they can subtracting each other.
Can I apply matrix subtracting idea to (Low - step) part?

Comment: Your matlab code is broken. For `Low < 0` no output is assigned. Besides this, `low` and `Low` are mixed. Replicating this function for any inputs is very complicated, please describe the intended input and output. As far as I read your comments, `Low` and `high` are two vectors/arrays, what is step?

Comment: Its not quite clear if this is operating on scalers or arrays. `rand` without argument just gives a scaler between 0 and 1 which suggests its scalers, `./` is normal division and `*` is normal multiplication.  The function looks like its trying to generate a number between low-(step/2) and high+(step/2) but does not quite as max value is low+high (when rand=1).

Answer (score 1):

I have no experiences with matlab, but [here's](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) the documentation (which you could have provided):

> x = A./B divides each element of A by the corresponding element of B.
>   Inputs A and B must have the same size unless one is a scalar value. A
>   scalar value is expanded into an array of the same size as the other
>   input.

So presuming that `A` is an `Double()` and `B` is a `Double()`  the result is a `Double()` where each value is the result of a division, you can use `Enumerable.Zip`:

```
Dim a As Double() = {1.5, 2, 5}
Dim b As Double() = {3.5, 4, 7}
Dim c As Double() = a.Zip(b, Function(aVal, bVal) aVal / bVal).ToArray()
```

But perhaps i've misunderstood the functionality, then explain it and provide sample data.

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for helping. However, I dont understand one thing about matlab. this function passing low, high, step. If my understand is correct(according to what you post), it is math operation of array. However,  When I check the code they are do mathematics operation such as (High - Low) if these variables are array then how do I handle (High - Low) ?

Comment: @BobMa: Use the matlab documentation. For vector inputs, both `-` and `./` are applied element-wise. Tim Schmelter already explained how to apply an operation element-wise to an array.

Comment: Matlab has particularly advanced array processing operations, it treats them in a way which is quite natural for mathematician and statisticians implementing vector and matrix operations. VB is a more general less specialised language without the specialised handling, you can even just add two arrays. 

Are low and high arrays or simply numbers? If they are just numbers (high - low) ./2 is just finding the mid-point between the two, (high-low) /2 will do. This generalises to work with two vectors, finding the mid point between them. For vectors and matrices there are other notions of division.